# Output voltage not changing with a constant current driver

Tags: led-driver, voltage-measurement, constant-current

If I attach a voltmeter to the output of this constant current driver and lower or raise the input voltage (100-230V,) the output voltage remains constant at 56V. Should it not fluctuate between 40-58V?

[image]

Comment: What's your load?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

This means this driver will output 350mA constant current, within an output voltage range of 40-58V.

So you can use it for a series string of LEDs that has a total forward voltage of 40-58V at 350mA. For example 16 white LEDs in series.

When there is no load (or just a multimeter) it will hit its max output voltage.

> If I ... lower or raise the input voltage (100-230V), the output voltage remains constant at 56V.

The driver is supposed to keep its output constant in spite of input voltage variations. That avoids light flickering.

Comment: OK, thanks so much - makes sense. What would then be the difference between this particular driver and one that is able to dim?

Comment: Dimmable one is able to vary output current.

Comment: LEDs have to be driven with current. The driver will set its output voltage to whatever the LEDs need to get the desired current and regulate based on current. It has an allowed output voltage range, that's mostly because the circuit uses a transformer which has a fixed turns ratio, so that sets some limits on output voltage.